# C# equivalent to java's wait and notify?

Tags: c#, java, multithreading

I am aware that you can lock an object in c# using lock but can you give up the lock and wait for something else to notify you that it's changed like you can in java with wait and notify?

It seems to me that synchronised and lock in java and c# respectively are synonomous.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The equivalent functionality (including the normal locking) is in the [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) class.

```
foo.notify() => Monitor.Pulse(foo)
foo.notifyAll() => Monitor.PulseAll(foo)
foo.wait() =>  Monitor.Wait(foo)
```

The `lock` statement in C# is equivalent to calling `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` with an appropriate try/finally block.

See [my threading tutorial](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/threads) or [Joe Albahari's one](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) for more details.

Comment: From Java API: wait() - Causes current thread to wait until either another thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object.  Your tutorial seems to be saying that Monitor.Wait() only waits if another thread is contending for a lock.

Comment: @ebyrob: Where does it suggest that?

Comment: oh sorry, it was the MSDN article that confused me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.wait%28v=vs.71%29.aspx  it says "//Wait, if the queue is busy. before calling: Monitor.Wait(m_smplQueue);" I was reading both at the same time and got confused about which is which.

Comment: I wrapped these in extension methods to make it easier to port my code from Java.

Comment: @SteveTaylor: On the other hand, that will have made it less idiomatic to anyone from a .NET background reading your code... I guess it depends on your team.

Comment: The team consists of me, a single founder bootstrapping his startup. The web application is in Java. The C# code is an API client running as a windows service, which I thought would be best done in C#. If/when I take on developers, well, they can change it to the more idiomatic form if they wish.

Answer (score 1):

I think Wait Handles may work for you. See if [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx) helps.